# Regex (preg_split): how do I split based on a delimiter, excluding delimiters included in a pair of quotes?

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I split this:

```
1 2 3 4/5/6 "7/8 9" 10
```

into this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
"7/8 9"
10
```

with preg_split()

So my question is, how do I split based on a delimiter, excluding delimiters inside a pair of quotes?

I kind of want to avoid capturing the things in quotes first and would ideally like it to be a one liner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following.

```
$text = '1 2 3 4/5/6 "7/8 9" 10';
$results = preg_split('~"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*F)|[ /]+~', $text);
print_r($results);
```

**Explanation**:

On the left side of the alternation operator we match anything in quotations making the subpattern **fail**, forcing the regular expression engine to not retry the substring using backtracking control with [`(*SKIP)` and `(*F)`](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt). The right side of the alternation operator matches either a space character or a forward slash not in quotations.

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => "7/8 9"
    [7] => 10
 )
```

Comment: lol. At first I interpreted that as sarcasm, then I remembered that this post is for regex. trololol.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
$s = '1 2 3 4/5/6 "7/8 9" 10';
$arr = preg_split('~("[^"]*")|[ /]+~', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

print_r( $arr );
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => "7/8 9"
    [7] => 10
)
```

Comment: +1 for use of useful `preg_split` flags that rarely show up in answers. :)

Comment: Thanks @zx81: Use of these flags makes regex pretty simple in this case which can be possibly used in non PCRE regex engines also.

Answer (score 4):

An other way with an optional group:

```
$arr = preg_split('~(?:"[^"]*")?\K[/\s]+~', $s);
```

The pattern `"[^"]*"[/\s]+` matches a quoted part followed by one or more spaces and slashes. But since you don't want to remove quoted parts, you put a `\K` after it. The `\K` removes all that have been matched on the left from the match result. With this trick, when a quoted part is found the regex engine returns only spaces or slashes after and split on them.

Since there are not always a quoted part before a space or a slash, you only need to make it optional with a non-capturing group `(?:...)` and a question mark `?`

Comment: Good use for `\K` here +1

Comment: Could you please explain what is going on in the expression?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @theamydance: I added an explanation.